# Home page refresh issue in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have developed website in nextjs framework. web page running localhost fine, I take build file after upload my hosting server but index page continuously refreshing but I do not add reload function but index page continuously refreshing. could you please solve this issue.

header.js

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";  
import Slider from "react-slick";   
import $ from "jquery"; 
var aed = { 
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    
    export default class Header extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            window.onscroll = function() {
                myFunction()
            };
            var header = document.getElementById("header");
            var sticky = header.offsetTop;
        
            function myFunction() {
                if(window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                    header.classList.add("sticky");
                } else {
                    header.classList.remove("sticky");
                }
            }
                $('.icon').click(function() {
                    $('#menu').toggleClass('responsive').toggleClass('topnav');
                });
                $('document').on('click','#menu p',function() {
                    $('.responsive').hide();
                });
          }
          
    render(){ 
  return (
    <> 
    <div className="container-fluid banner">
        <div className="row" id="header">
        <div className="col-md-4"> <a href="/">
            <img src="/images/logo.png" width="170px" height="65px" className="logo" alt='Znap Logo'/></a>
             <a className="icon">
                <img src='/images/menubar.png' className='fa fa-bars icons' alt='Menu Icon'/></a></div>
            <div className="col-md-8 cat">
                <ul id="menu" className="menus">
                    <li>
                     <a href="all-offers">
                        <p>All Offers<span className="pip">|</span></p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>

                     <a href="/#categories">
                        <p>All Categories</p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li>
                     <p className="menu"> <span className="pip">|</span><Link href="/how-it-work"><a>How it Works</a></Link></p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/#download-app">
                     <p className="menu"><span className="pip">|</span>Download App</p>
                 </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="lfc col-md-6 ">
                {/* <h1>SAVE on every Spend</h1> */}
                <h1>Upto <span className='upto'>50%</span> Cashback on your spends</h1>
                {/* <p>With Znap, get save on your daily spends at local businesses in UAE. Choose your style of saving between cash back and discounts.</p> */}
                <p className="m-c"><span><a href="#download-app">Get Started</a></span></p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 m-l"> <img src="/images/hand-mobile.png" alt="Hand" width="" height="" className="handimg"/>
                {/* <div className="box-radius "> */}
                    {/* <p className="small-icon"><img src="/images/logo.png" width="40px" height="15px" alt='slider-logo'/><span>1m ago</span></p> */}
                    {/* <div className="aed-slider">
                        <Slider {...aed}>
                        <div>
                        <span className='minutes'>1m ago</span>
                            <img src="https://dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net/stores/Bombay_Chowpatty_Detail_page_1634649820602.jpg" className='img-fluid'/>
                            <h5 className='small-slider-1'>Shakey's Pizza</h5>
                            <p className='small-slider-2'>You've saved AED 20 on your transactions at Shakey's Pizza.</p>
                            <div id='cash-discount'><div className='cash-discount'><p>Cashback</p><p className='small-percent' style={{ color: '#0065ae' }}>50%</p></div><div className='cash-discount'><p>Discount</p><p className="small-percent" style={{ color: '#ec008c' }}>10%</p></div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="https://dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net/stores/Bombay_Chowpatty_Detail_page_1634649820602.jpg" className='img-fluid'/>
                            <h5 className='small-slider-1'>Shakey's Pizza</h5>
                            <p className='small-slider-2'>You've saved AED 20 on your transactions at Shakey's Pizza.</p>
                            <div id='cash-discount'><div className='cash-discount'><p>Cashback</p><p className='small-percent' style={{ color: '#0065ae' }}>50%</p></div><div className='cash-discount'><p>Discount</p><p className="small-percent" style={{ color: '#ec008c' }}>10%</p></div></div>
                        </div>
                        </Slider>
                    </div>
                </div> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     
  </>
  )
}
}
 footer.js:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
export default class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
      
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container-fluid footer">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-12">
                <h2 className="text-left t-l">About Znap</h2>
                <p className="t-l">Get Real Cash on everyday purchases.</p>
                <p className="t-l">UAE’s no.1 free cash rewards app, Znap App is the ultimate destination for everyday savings that offers you amazing daily deals. Earn cash rewards on over 100+ Brands and Local Stores’ and make sure you enjoy all our shopping benefits while you’re on the go…</p>
            </div>
         
            <div className="col-md-2 col-12">
               <div>
               <p><Link href="all-offers"><a>All Offers</a></Link></p>
                 <p><Link href="faq"><a>FAQ</a></Link></p>
                 <p><Link href="partners"><a>Partners</a></Link></p>
                 <p><Link href="privacy"><a>Privacy</a></Link></p>
                  {/* <p><a href="https://www.znap.cash/business/">Business</a></p> */}
               </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 col-12">
                <h2>Follow us</h2>
                <p className="tcenter social"><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/znap.cash/"><img src="images/instagram.jpg" alt="znap instagram"/></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/znap.cash/"><img src="images/fb.jpg" alt="znap facebook"/></a></span><a href="https://twitter.com/znapcash/" ><img src="images/twitter.png" className="twitter" alt="znap twitter"/></a></p>
                <h2>Download Znap</h2>
                <p className="tcenter marketplace"><span><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macappstudio.znap&hl=en"><img src="images/playstore.png" alt="znap playstore"/></a><a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/znap/id1013991450"><img src="images/appstore.png" alt="znap app store"/></a></span></p>
            </div> 
            
        </div>
    </div>
     
    <div className="container-fluid" id="copyright">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <p className="copyright"><span className="pull-left">© 2016 - 2022 Inquest Technologies FZE. All Rights Reserved.</span><span className="pull-right"><Link href="terms"><a>Terms</a></Link> & <Link href="privacy"><a>Privacy</a></Link></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

body section newstores.js:

```
// import img from 'next/img';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";  
import Slider from "react-slick";  
var testimonial = { 
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 3000,
  autoplay: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
  };
  var settings={
    nav: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 100, 
    dots:true,
    autoplay: false,
    slidesToShow:4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                dots: false
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                dots: false,
                slidesToScroll: 2 
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow:1,
                dots: false,
                nav:false,
                speed: 200,
                slidesToScroll: 2,                        
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '40px'
            }
        }
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
    ]
  }
   
export default class Newstores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.newStoreList,
      dataMenu:props.menu,
      visible: 4,
      isLoading: true,
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  } 
  loadMore() {
    this.setState({
        visible: this.state.visible + 4,
        dataLoaded: this.state.visible >= this.state.data.length
    });
  }
  render(){
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!this.state.dataMenu) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log(this.state.data)
  return (
  <>
    
    <div className="container pl">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 heading ">
                <h2>What's New?</h2>
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr1' />
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr2' /> </div>
             
        </div>
        <div className="row whatnew" id="what-new" >
    
        {/* {this.state.data.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((x, i) => {
            return ( */}
            <div className="col-md-12">
            <Slider {...settings}>
            {this.state.data.map((x,i) =>(
         <div className="" key={i}>
             
             <div class='bg-info'>
             <Link href={"/store"+"/"+x.store_label+"/"+x.store_id } passHref={true}>
             <a><img src={x.logo} className='img-fluid' alt=''/></a>
             </Link>
             <h2> <Link href={"/store"+"/"+x.store_label+"/"+x.store_id } passHref={true}><a>{x.store_name}</a></Link></h2>
             <p>{x.summary}</p>
             {x.cashback_offer!=="" && x.discount_offer!=="" ? 
               <div id='cash-discount'><div className='cash-discount'><p>Cashback</p><p>{x.cashback_offer}</p></div><div className='cash-discount'><p>Discount</p><p style={{ color: '#ec008c' }}>{x.discount_offer}</p></div></div>
            
              :x.cashback_offer.length!==0 ?
               <div id='cash-discount' ><div className='cash-discount' id='cb'><p>Cashback</p><p >{x.cashback_offer}</p></div></div>
            
              :x.discount_offer.length!==0 ?
               <div id='cash-discount'><div className='cash-discount' id='ds'><p>Discount</p><p style={{ color: '#ec008c' }}>{x.discount_offer}</p></div></div>
               : "Neither"}
              
        </div>
       
        </div>
            ))}
            </Slider>
            </div>
        {/* {
        !this.state.dataLoaded && (
          <p class="category-more offer-more" onClick={this.loadMore}><span>See More <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></span></p>
           
    )
} */}
    
        </div>
        
        {/* <div className="row refer" style={{marginTop: "50px"}}>
            <div className="col-md-6 heading"> <img src="images/email-subscribe.png" class="subscribe" />
                <h2>Get the latest & <br/>Best offers Alerts</h2>
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr1' />
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr2' />
                <form className="subscribe-form">
                    <div className="input-group mb-3 newsletter">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email Address"/>
                        <div className="input-group-append"> <span className="input-group-text">SUBSCRIBE</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 heading"> <img src="images/refer.png" class="refer" />
                <h2  >Refer & Earn</h2>
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr1' />
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr2' />
                <p id="download-app">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          */}
    </div>
       <div className="container-fluid start-earn" id='download-app'>
       <div className="row">
         <div className="col-md-12">
           <h2>START EARNING TODAY!</h2>
           <p>Download Znap and Earn cash rewards by completing one of many simples tasks.</p>
           <p><span className="download"><b>Download App</b> </span><span><a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/znap/id1013991450"><img src="images/apple.png" className="apple" alt="Apple Store"/></a><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macappstudio.znap&amp;hl=en"><img src="images/google.png" className="playstore" alt="Play Store"/></a></span></p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div className="container testinomial">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 heading">
                <h2>Here is what our<br/> Happy Customers have to say!</h2>
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr1' />
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr2' /> </div>
            <div className="col-md-12">
        
                <div className="testinomial-slider">
        <Slider {...testimonial}>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Awez Harge</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Znap pay is best even you can do payments by just referring others you can shop or eat for free. Easy to use fully satisfied and Happy</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Hamza Danawala</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Best app!! Always handy for me to save some extra bucks from my monthly budget...I know the cash back amount or reward points are not that huge but it feels good when I see those confirmation emails for my cashback approval, as if I have won jackpot. I have been using Znap since 2019 and amazed to see the amount of small retailers along with big brands being added every month. Good Job Team. All the Best for future.
</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Abhya Kumar</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Good app. Offers and Cash Back are real. Just used at a ombre salon dso and got 40% cash back which I used again to discount my next bill. Amazing how it works. Lots of places to get cash rewards from in Dubai. Note they allow you to earn through referrals and also give free vouchers to spend for every 5 successful referrals. Recommend it. Try it.
</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Kumar S</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Great app. I spent at Kulfilicious and got cash back. They may need to work on the app looks a bit. But the cash back actually works. Listed places like Kulfilicious and Bombay chowpatty and other nice places in and around Al Karama area  Got 30 AED via referrals too. I think its worth trying the app as we earn Cash Back for almost everything</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Mano shaluigate</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Good app for incremental savings. Thanks</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="images/testimonial-user.png"/>
                        <h3>Saeed Ahmed</h3>
                        <p><i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star checked"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i> <i className="fa fa-star"></i></p>
                        <p>Amazing app enjoying alot with family to eat outside.</p>
                    </div>
                    </Slider>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div className="container categories" id="categories">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 heading">
                <h2 style={{marginTop: '40px'}}>Store Categories</h2>
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr1' />
                <hr className='horizontal-line hr2' /> </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row" id="category">
    {this.state.dataMenu.map((x,i) =>(
     
        <div className='col-md-3 col-4' key={i}>
           <Link href={"category"+"/" + x.category_label + "/"+ x.id } passHref={true}>
             <a><img src={x.image}/></a>
             </Link>
             <p><Link href={"category"+"/" + x.category_label + "/"+ x.id } passHref={true}><a>{x.category_name}</a></Link></p>
             
     </div>
        
    ))}
        </div>
    </div>
    

</>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: Shall i share my website link?

Comment: Yes, Also share any code snippet that you think might contain any error.

Comment: @Jay I added home page js file.

Comment: Console.log() your variables, page is refreshed because some params are null (my opinion)

Comment: Please try and provide a [mre].